# PHP function IF else regarding booking room availability

Tags: wordpress

I have an issue with a booking plugin in WordPress. If a room is booked, it is showing the room in search results just with a "NOT AVAILABLE" label. From a UX perspective it is a better option to not show it at all if the room is booked.

I found the code controlling the issue:

```
    //available or not
if ( nd_booking_is_qnt_available(nd_booking_is_available($nd_booking_id,$nd_booking_date_from,$nd_booking_date_to),$nd_booking_date_from,$nd_booking_date_to,$nd_booking_id) == 1 ) {
    $nd_booking_availability = "";
}else{
    $nd_booking_availability = "<span class='nd_options_color_white nd_booking_font_size_10 nd_booking_line_height_10 nd_booking_letter_spacing_2 nd_booking_padding_3_5 nd_booking_top_10 nd_booking_position_absolute nd_booking_right_10 nd_booking_bg_yellow'>".__('NOT AVAILABLE','nd-booking')."</span>";
}
```

I tried a few options but they always generate a blank page. Any idea what should be written after "else" so that the booked room won't show at all in search results?

Comment: Sounds like you need a wrapper function around that complicated logic so you can do a simple `if` test somewhere else.

Comment: Hi, i am not that good, i tried basic things like adding 0 to function $nd_booking_availability and removing the span class, but that just removes the label heh :/

Comment: I think the problem is this chunk of code only has a side-effect, it doesn't have a useful return value.

Comment: Hi, i enter return 0 value after else, then the booked rooms does not display, but shows a empty space instead. How can it continue the loop of available rooms, and not displaying the one thats booked? Full code: https://pastebin.com/sXmaUvap

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this logic either prepends nothing or prepends the 'NOT AVAILABLE' string. It does nothing to control displaying the rest of the room information.

You will need to find the logic where it outputs the rest of the room and wrap the entire thing in:

```
if ( ! nd_booking_is_qnt_available(nd_booking_is_available($nd_booking_id,$nd_booking_date_from,$nd_booking_date_to),$nd_booking_date_from,$nd_booking_date_to,$nd_booking_id) == 1 ) {
    // Here is the room output logic
}
```

Comment: Hmm, i understand what you mean, here is the whole code: https://pastebin.com/sXmaUvap

Comment: Hi, i enter return 0 value after else, then the booked rooms does not display, but shows a empty space instead. How can it continue the loop of available rooms, and not displaying the one thats booked? Full code: https://pastebin.com/sXmaUvap

Comment: There's probably still a wrapper outside your if/else that has been styled to hold a room information. Examine the outputted html and then make sure your if/else wraps everything it needs to.